# Adding single item to set in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities

I wonderig if it is possible to add a record to a set of items based on a particular condition?

I have this:

```
var gear = db.Gears.Where(g => g.Name.StartsWith(term))
            .Take(10)
            .Select(g => new { label = g.Name });
```

Now, if there is NOT an exact match between g.Name and term I want to add an item with label

```
"Add " + term
```

to the set. This is for a jQuery UI Autocomplete box. So the idea is to present an "add item" suggestion if there is no exact match.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not:

```
if (!gear.Any(g => g.Name.Equals(item)) 
  gear = gear.Concat(new[] { new { label = "Add " + item } });
```

Although, you may need to add a `AsEnumerable()` call at the end of your original query to ensure that `gear` is type inferred as `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IQueryable<T>`

Comment: Hm, thanks for your example. However, the set need to add the "Add item" value if the set does not conatain the **exact** match. The set is not necessarily empty (note the "StartsWith()" in the query).

I'm not sure how I add an item to an existing set...

Comment: Works very good. Except there's a parentesis missing and "g.Name" should be g.label. (wich I changed in your answer)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should to the trick:

```
var gear = db.Gears.Where(g => g.Name.StartsWith(term))
    .Select(g => new {label = g.Name != term ? "Add " + term : g.Name})
    .Take(10);
```

You could consider refactoring the last part into a separate function:

```
private string GetLabel(Gear gear, string term)
{
    return gear.Name != term ? "Add " + term : gear.Name;
}
```